# Vue js item deletion from list

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have a list of components rendered through v-for. Here is the sample code:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items">
  <component1 v-if="item.type=='type1'" v-bind:prop-attrs="item" :key="item.id" v-bind:item-index="index" > </component1>
  <component2 v-if="item.type=='type2'" v-bind:prop-attrs="item" :key="item.id" v-bind:item-index="index" > </component2>
</div>
```

I am trying to delete items from the array:

```
removeItem(index){
   this.$delete(this.items,index);        
}
```

Above code is removing the element from array but it returns following error:

```
vue_2.6.10.js?ver=5.2.2:6 TypeError: Cannot read property '__ob__' of undefined
    at a.e.$destroy (vue_2.6.10.js?ver=5.2.2:6)
    at destroy (vue_2.6.10.js?ver=5.2.2:6)
    at b (vue_2.6.10.js?ver=5.2.2:6)
    at b (vue_2.6.10.js?ver=5.2.2:6)
    at b (vue_2.6.10.js?ver=5.2.2:6)
    at a.__patch__ (vue_2.6.10.js?ver=5.2.2:6)
    at a.e.$destroy (vue_2.6.10.js?ver=5.2.2:6)
    at destroy (vue_2.6.10.js?ver=5.2.2:6)
    at b (vue_2.6.10.js?ver=5.2.2:6)
    at $ (vue_2.6.10.js?ver=5.2.2:6)
```

I am not sure what is going wrong. Please advise.

Comment: What index are you passing in? Error suggests you are attempting to delete something that doesn't exist.

Comment: The index seems to be correct. I also tried with 0 index : this.$delete(this.items,0)

Comment: Add the actual code, it's hard to debug without seeing it all

Comment: can you share the code around `this.$delete(this.items,index);` especially? I wonder if there might be a context where `this` might not refer the the context to the instance and `this.items` is therefore undefined?

Comment: @TobiasG. Ther are no other statements in the remove method. I have added the method in the question. I think I would like to mention is that I am inserting an object into the array.

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with what you've shared here - many possibilities. Like @RalphKing wrote, we need more code.

Comment: @TobiasG. Okay, I will try to share my code. But I think I found the problem. While mounting I have 7 objects in my array. After deletion, it has 6 but somehow my loop is trying to run till 7th object which is Vue observer (after deletion). I hope this might help.

Comment: Found the problem. In my comonent data property was incorrectly configured. I missed the return {} in function.